# How is an ordered pair that belongs to $R^2$ x $R^3$ different from a list that belongs to $R^5$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

According to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzVBTNf6Z3M) (at 3:05), the author says that $R^2$ x $R^3$ ≠ $R^5$ as the object of $R^2$ x $R^3$ [(($x_1$,$x_2$),($x_3$,$x_4$,$x_5$)) : $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$,$x_5$ ∈ R] is different from an object of $R^5$ [($x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$,$x_5$) : $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$,$x_5$ ∈ R] in the sense that the objects in $R^2$ x $R^3$ is an ordered pair, whereas the objects in $R^5$ are lists of length five.

My doubt here is, how is an ordered pair that belongs to $R^2$ x $R^3$ different from a list that belongs to $R^5$ ?

Comment: $((x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4,x_5))$ is different from $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ in that they look different. One of them has more parentheses than the other. They are different in much the same way that *Hello* and *Bonjour* are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are only formally different. The length of an object in $\mathbb R^2×\mathbb R^3$ is two (an ordered pair may be considered a length-$2$ list), while that of an object in $\mathbb R^5$ is five.

The first-glance intuition that they are the same is formalised by a trivial *bijection* between the two spaces.

Comment: @joriki I had "length" in place of "dimension" here. Would that be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, I think that's less misunderstandable.

Comment: I didn't quite get this one. Isn't $R^2$ x $R^3$ isomorphic to $R^5$ ? In that case wouldn't both $R^2$ x $R^3$ and $R^5$ and thus their objects have the same dimension ? Also, is there a way to visualize this ? (For e.g. $R^1$ x $R^2$ vs $R^3$ if possible)

Comment: @maheshRao $\mathbb R^2×\mathbb R^3$ is a vector in the plane and a vector in 3D space. $\mathbb R^5$ is a vector in 5D space.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Ohh. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sense, in which you can consider them exactly equal. For simplicity consider $R\times R^2$ and $R^3$.

We define an $n$-tuple as follows:

> $(x_1,x_2)$ is the set $\{x_1,\{x_1,x_2\}\}$.
>
> By induction, we define an $n$-tuple as $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ as
>   $(x_1,(x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1}))$.

It is now easy to see that $R\times R^2=R^3$.

To illustrate, note that $$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,(x_2,x_3))=\{x_1,\{x_1,(x_2,x_3)\}\}=\{x_1,\{x_1,\{x_2,\{x_2,x_3\}\}\}\}.$$ So $R^3$ consists of all such sets.

Now consider $R\times R^2$. An element of $R\times R^2$ is of the form $(a,b)$ with $a\in R$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)\in R^2$. In other words an arbitrary element of $R\times R^2$ is

$$(a,b)=\{a,\{a,b\}\}=\{a,\{a,(b_1,b_2)\}\}=\{a,\{a,\{b_1,\{b_1,b_2\}\}\}\}.$$

So $R\times R^2$ consists of all such sets.
At this point it is clear that $R\times R^2=R^3$. Similarly, $R^n\times R^m=R^{mn}$.

Comment: This should only work if $n = 1$, right? Otherwise you really have to write down some bijection.

Comment: I haven't really tried it but I think that if $n>1$ modifying the definition of the $k$-tuple appropriately would still accomplish the trick.